# How to calculated angular variable in braces

Tags: angularjs, curly-braces

I have this code:

```
    <pre>totalItems: {{vm.pagination.totalItems}}</pre>
    <pre>items-per-page: {{vm.pagination.itemsPerPage}}</pre>
    <pre>Total: Math.ceil({{vm.pagination.totalItems / vm.pagination.itemsPerPage}})</pre>
```

Output:

[image]

I'm using `Math.ceil()` so the answer should be `11` but I'm not getting the correct answer as below:

[image]

How can I calculate angular value in braces? Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use Math in the view, unless you define it as part of your scope ($scope.Math = Math //in your controller). And in that case it would be {{ Math.ceil(whatever number) }}

Comment: To support @yBrodsky answer, here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29519/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create a scoped function:

```
<pre>Total: {{calculateTotal(vm.pagination.totalItems, vm.pagination.itemsPerPage)}}</pre>
```

Then add the function to the scope:

```
$scope.calculateTotal = function(totalItems, itemsPerPage) {
  return Math.ceil(totalItems/itemsPerPage);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('foo', function($scope) {

var vm = this;

vm.w = {
pagination: {
 totalItems: 258,
 itemsPerPage: 25
}
}

init();

return vm.w;

function init() {
 vm.w.pagination.calculation = Math.ceil(vm.w.pagination.totalItems / vm.w.pagination.itemsPerPage)
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="foo as vm">

 <pre>totalItems: {{vm.pagination.totalItems}}</pre>
    <pre>items-per-page: {{vm.pagination.itemsPerPage}}</pre>
    <pre>Total: {{vm.pagination.calculation}}</pre>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use `Math` in the template, you will need to expose it. So in your controller you would set

```
vm.Math = Math;
```

and you would then use it in the template like so:

```
<pre>Total: {{ vm.Math.ceil(vm.pagination.totalItems / vm.pagination.itemsPerPage }})</pre>
```

However, rather than doing the calculation in the template you would be better off exposing a function that calculates the value in your controller:

```
vm.getTotalPageCount = function() {
    return Math.ceil(vm.pagination.totalItems / vm.pagination.itemsPerPage);
};
```

And use it in your template:

```
<pre>Total: {{ vm.getTotalPageCount() }})</pre>
```